# Error in ListView: InvalidArgument = Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

This error appears when I select some item in ListView for the second time. I tried to debug it, and when I select some item for the second time, the `list_answers.SelectedItems.Count` is 0. Why?
Here is my code:

```
private void list_answers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewItem t = list_answers.SelectedItems[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Count; i++)
            {
                if (t.Text == "Question №" + (i + 1))
                {
                    this.ShowOnePanel(i);
                    iter = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: No. My items consists of text and image. Firstly, images are set to null. When I give a correct answer to some question, then I set a image to that item(question) to mark it as corrct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When changing selection, the ListView will first deselect current row and then select new one, so you will have a call where SelectedItems will be empty.

You can solve it by Adding

```
if(list_answers.SelectedIndex == -1)
    return;

or

if(list_answers.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
    return;
```

Comment: ty, it helps. I have one more question: I have a function, when some question is shown, then is ListView this question is selected. It works with ListBox, but doesn't with ListView.                           private void SelectedQuestion(int number)
        {
            this.list_answers.Items[number].Selected = true;            
        }

Comment: Are you sure it's not selected? If the ListView loses the focus and you did not highlighted the row, you will not see the row as selected until it regains focus. Also, if the answer was valid please accept it.

Comment: if I go through questions fast, I can see that proper "questions" in ListView blink. But why it is not highlighed?

Comment: Because you must set explicitly HideSelection = false on your ListView ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you just add this code in the listview_SelectedChangeIndex event, it will solve the problem.

```
 if (finishListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
// here your code goes
    }
    else
    {
    return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good description about this problem in the link below:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?753867-RESOLVED-InvalidArgument-Value-of-0-is-not-valid-for-index-Parameter-name-index