# C# - listview error on adding value of column1 and column 2

Tags: c#, winforms

```
for (int i = 1; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    double cts = 0;
                    cts = double.Parse(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text) + double.Parse(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[5].Text);
                    listView1.Items[i].SubItems[7].Text = cts.ToString() ;
                }
```

The idea is to Add the value of column 1 and column 2 and put it on column 3, The code runs after the listview is populated

And when I run it an error is shown: InvalidArgument=Value of '7' is not valid for 'index'.Parameter name: index

Comment: Is there an item under index 7? as far as the error says there is nothing. Maybe you meant index 6? since it is the column index 4 and 5 I assume the third one is under index 6?

Comment: It's 7, 6 is column for date

Comment: Have a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050500/error-in-listview-invalidargument-value-of-0-is-not-valid-for-index Might be the same issue.

Comment: @vsarunov same error, but not the same issue

Comment: Have you tried debugging and breakpointing on the line where you are trying to set the value and looking what does the list contain what subItems and etc?

Comment: tried that it show the right data and the variable cts shows the right sum

Comment: What does the SubItems container, how many items?

Comment: it has 8///////

Comment: But when i try to add it to subitem[6] it works

Comment: So my first comment is valid.

Comment: Nope, I need it to be in 7 cant change the column order

Comment: @Captchan please provide us your population code and listview settings.